# Creating a big int

Tags: c

im trying to implement bit shifting to bigints. The BigInt is represented by an array of bytes that should be interpreted as a single integer N bits in two's complement. So i want to make something like:

Example array bigint: 
{0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF} would represent the integer 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE (-2) N = 128 bits.

typedef unsigned char *BigInt;

when i try to create my bigint im getting errors

```
#include <stdlib.h>

    void bi_init (int nbits)
    {
        nbytes = (nbits/8);
    }

    BigInt bi_new (int val)
    {
        BigInt new = (BigInt)malloc(nbytes*sizeof(unsigned char));

        new=val --> problem, can someone give me a hint on how can i implement this array?

        return novo;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should use the same identifier `novo` consistently instead of a mixture with `new`? And why did you not give us the precise error message?

Comment: Don't `typedef` pointer types unless they are truly opaque.  It causes more harm then good, don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef unsigned char *BigInt;

BigInt *new = (BigInt)malloc(nbytes*sizeof(unsigned char));
```

You declare `new` as an `unsigned char**`, that's one level of pointers too many (and you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc` in C).

Assuming that `novo` and `new` are the same variable and only one occurrence has been translated for the post,

novo=val

overwrites the just allocated address with the passed-in `val`.

To fill the allocated buffer with the bytes of `val`,

```
int i = 0;
// make it unsigned, so that right-shifting works correctly
unsigned int u_val = val;
while(u_val) {
    new[i++] = u_val&0xFF;
    u_val >>= 8;
}
```

Then there remains the problem

```
nbytes = (nbits/8);
```

that you're allocating too little memory if `nbits` is not a multiple of 8, make that

```
nbytes = (nbits+7)/8;
```